# How to do MD5 hashing of as string in athena?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

MD5 hashing function in athena is not working for string. However, athena's document shows that it does : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MD5.html

Not sure what I am missing here. If I transform varchar to varbinary then the hash that gets generated are not correct.

Getting this error :

````
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (varchar(15)) for function md5. Expected: md5(varbinary)

This query ran against the "temp" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: dd959e8a-7fa4-4170-8895-ce7cf58be6ea.```
````

Comment: The documentation you are linking to is from Redshift, not Athena.

Answer (score 11):

The [`md5`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/binary.html#md5) function in Athena/Presto takes binary input. You can convert a string to a varbinary using the [`to_utf8`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html#to_utf8) function:

```
SELECT md5(to_utf8('hello world'))
```

Comment: The links don't work anymore. Here's a page which contains [md5](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html) and here is a page which contains [to_utf8](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html).